# Create new data frame column

Tags: r, apply

My data frame looks like that:

```
df <- data.frame(INFO=c("A;B;C", "B;A;C"), METRICS=c("1;2;3", "4;5;6"))
df
   INFO METRICS
1 A;B;C   1;2;3
2 B;A;C   4;5;6
```

I am trying to catch the value of 'A' for each line using `apply()` and store the resulting vector in a new column of my original data frame:

```
df$M1 <- apply(
   df,
   1,
   function(x){
      info <- unlist(strsplit(x[1], ";"))
      metric <- unlist(strsplit(x[2], ";"))
      for(i in 1:3){
         ifelse(
            info[i]=="A", 
            metric[i],
            "."
         )
      }
   }
)
```

In order to get the following result:

```
df
   INFO METRICS M1
1 A;B;C   1;2;3  1
2 B;A;C   4;5;6  5
```

But the new column is not created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split the string on `";"` and use `mapply` to get the corresponding value of `METRICS` where `INFO == "A"`.

```
df$M1 <- mapply(function(x, y) y[x == "A"], strsplit(df$INFO, ";"),
                                            strsplit(df$METRICS, ";"))
df

#   INFO METRICS M1
#1 A;B;C   1;2;3  1
#2 B;A;C   4;5;6  5
```

**data**

Make sure the data is read as characters and not as factors.

```
df <- data.frame(INFO=c("A;B;C", "B;A;C"), METRICS=c("1;2;3", "4;5;6"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the `apply` like below

```
df$M1<-apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  unlist(strsplit(x[2],split = ";"))[unlist(strsplit(x[1],";"))=="A"]
})
```

such that

```
> df
   INFO METRICS M1
1 A;B;C   1;2;3  1
2 B;A;C   4;5;6  5
```

Answer (score 1):

A vectorized way to do it is to unlist after spliting and make it a named vector, i.e.

```
i1 <- setNames(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$METRICS), ';')), 
               unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$INFO), ';')))
```

then simply,

```
i1[names(i1) == 'A']
#  A   A 
#"1" "5"
```

Or add it to your data frame,

```
 df$M1 <- i1[names(i1) == 'A']

#   INFO METRICS M1
#1 A;B;C   1;2;3  1
#2 B;A;C   4;5;6  5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `grepRaw()`:

```
ind <- sapply(df$INFO, grepRaw, pattern = "A", fixed = TRUE)
substring(df$METRICS, ind, ind)

[1] "1" "5"
```